# Ruby login page that uses SimpleSAMLphp as authentication

Tags: ruby, web-applications, sinatra, simplesamlphp

I've been searching for a while for a solution to my needs. Here's what's needed:

- Ruby webapp (not Ruby on Rails).
- Sinatra
- Login page which uses [SimpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/) for authentication (redirect to our SimpleSAMLphp, authenticate, then go back to our app to do an action).

Is this possible? If not, if someone can point me to the right direction I'd  be grateful!

Comment: More than likely, as SimpleSAMLphp supports OAuth. Check out https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-saml